# Creating MYSQL tables

Tags: mysql, create-table

I created this table on MYSQL:

```
CREATE TABLE Enrolled (   
    snum int,      
    cname varchar(60),  
    PRIMARY KEY (snum,cname)  
    FOREIGN KEY (snum)  
    REFERENCES Student(id),  
    FOREIGN KEY (cname)  
    REFERENCES Class(name)  
) ENGINE = INNOdb;
```

- How do I put a minimum and maximum number of rows? For example, If I want the table to have minimum 5 rows but not exceed 30 rows? (Each class needs at least 5 students but no more than 30 students)
- How do I establish on MYSQL that each student must be enrolled in at least two courses?

Comment: Why do you have such a complicated naming policy?

Comment: you have to do those in your application code. You can do it with triggers but it's better to have the application handle the logic.

Comment: _“I want the table to have minimum 5 rows but not exceed 30 rows? (Each class needs at least 5 students but no more than 30 students)”_ – if a “class” is not the same as the table, then the first part does not even make sense.

Comment: You're right in general, to try to put the logic into the database instead of the application because this is where it preferably belongs. But for such a case you'd need constraint triggers that fire at the end of a transaction, not at every statement like Postgres' deferrable constraint triggers. MySQL doesn't support such a concept to my knowledge. So either switch to a more capable DBMS or put it in the application even though it better belonged to the database.